# Prove that $\frac{-n}{\ln (\prod_{i=1}^n X_i)}$ converges to $\alpha$ almost surely

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, maximum-likelihood, law-of-large-numbers

I'm solving the following exercise from previous final exam:

> For $\alpha \in (0,1)$, we define the following density function $$f (x; \alpha) = \alpha x^{\alpha -1} \mathbf{1}_{[0,1]} (x)$$
>
> We consider a sample $(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ of i.i.d. random variables with density $f$. Prove that the maximum likelihood estimator $\hat\alpha_n$ of $\alpha$ converges to $\alpha$ almost surely as $n \to \infty$.

After writing down the log likelihood function, I use FOC and SOC to get $$\hat\alpha_n = \frac{-n}{\ln (\prod_{i=1}^n X_i)}$$

Then I'm stuck at proving $\hat\alpha_n$ converges to $\alpha$ almost surely. How can I proceed to finish the proof? Many thanks!

Comment: Do you know strong law of large numbers? Write the MLE as $\hat\alpha_n=\frac{-1}{\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n \ln X_i}$ and apply the strong law.

Comment: Thank you @StubbornAtom! It's my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $\mathbb E [\ln X_1 ] = -1/\alpha$. By SLLN, $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\ln (X_i)$ converges almost surely to $-1/\alpha$. Then by continuous mapping theorem, we get $\hat\alpha_n$ converges almost surely to $\alpha$.

Comment: Oh my bad @StubbornAtom :(